# Distinct aggregation in pre-calculated measure (MDX)

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, mdx, data-warehouse

There are two measures in one fact table \ dimension. Measure '**YearTotal**' should somehow be pre-calcuated as a distinct value for any futher summing (aggregating). And 'YearTotal' can't be derived from 'YearDetail' measure, so they are completely independent.

```
 +-------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
| AccountingID |      Date     | TotalYear | YearDetail |
+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
|   account1   |    31.12.2012 |       500 |          7 |
|   account1   |    31.12.2012 |       500 |          3 |
|   account1   |    31.12.2012 |       500 |          1 |
|   account2   |    31.12.2012 |       900 |         53 |
|   account2   |    31.12.2012 |       900 |          4 |
|   account2   |    31.12.2012 |       900 |          9 |
|   account3   |    31.12.2012 |       203 |         25 |
|   account3   |    31.12.2012 |       203 |         11 | 
|   account3   |    31.12.2012 |       203 |         17 |
+--------------+---------------+-----------+------------+
```

**So, the question:** What should be in (pre)calculated measure expression to get such a result:

```
select 

    (
    [Accounting Dim].[Account ID]
    [Dim Date].[Calendar Year].&[2012]
    ) ON COLUMNS
    
    from [Cube]
    
    WHERE [Measures].[YearTotal]
```

**in case of correct expression the answer would be** --> (500+900+203) = **1603**

(and optionaly): maybe there is a common distinct pattern solution for any other simple types of aggregation

Answer (score 1):

Maybe go with MAX at the column level [TotalYear] and enforce a specific level of calculation.

```
CREATE MEMBER [Measures].[YearTotal] AS 
    MAX(
        (
            [Calendar Dim].[Year].[All].Children, 
            [Accounting Dim].[Account ID].[All].Children
        ),
        [Measures].[TotalYear]
    )
```

Comment: Still cant't get (and while do no see logic 'how' looking at this example) distinct summarizing. I've tried different aggregations with base measure 'TotalYear', and then applied your solution. My current idea to solve it somehow in another way - to add a new one column which would count only first row of repeated sequences 'AccountingID, Date, TotalYear' with value (for example '1', the others may still NULL). As a 3-rd slice of the cube (Maybe kind of this you meant 'enforce a specific level of calculation').